# How to I get the bottom half of my menu buttons to show?

Tags: css, menu, navigation, hover

I can't seem to get the bottom of the buttons to show, I tried increasing padding on the span, setting it to display: block, and increasing the height of the A and SPAN elements to no avail.

JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/7tcrz38r/

CSS:

```
/* Menu */
div#menu{
    float: right;
    margin-top: [[setting:menuMarginTop]];
}

div#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#menu>ul>li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}
div#menu li.has-sub>ul{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 4px solid [[setting:color1]] !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 110px;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: -12px 0 0 16px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 2000;
}
div#menu li.has-sub>ul>li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 10px;
}
div#menu li.has-sub>ul>li>a{
    color: #949494;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div#menu li.has-sub>ul>li>a:hover{
    color: [[setting:color1]];
}

div#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

div#menu>ul>li>a {
    color: #868787;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 1px !important;
    margin: 17px 15px !important;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
/*div#menu>ul>li>a.active{
    color: [[setting:color1]] !important;
    background-color: #c3d9e3;
    border: 2px solid #abd1eb;
    border-radius: 5px;
}*/
div#menu>ul>li:last-child>a{
    margin: 17px 0 17px 15px !important
}
div#menu>ul>li:last-child>a{
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
div#menu>ul>li>a:hover,
div#menu>ul>li>a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

div#menu>ul>li>a{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 1.3em !important;
}

div#menu>ul>li>a>span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #eef3f5;
    /*-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;*/
}

div#menu>ul>li>a>span::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    /*-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);*/
}

div#menu>ul>li>a:hover span,
div#menu>ul>li>a:focus span {
/*    background-color: #c3d9e3;
    border: 1px solid #abd1eb;
    border-radius: 25%;*/
    background-color: #c3d9e3;
    border: 2px solid #abd1eb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    color: [[setting:color1]];*/
}
/*
div#menu>ul>li>a.menuactive{
    color: [[setting:color1]];
}*/
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
                        <ul><li >
                                <a href="#"><span data-hover="Home">Home</span></a></li><li >
                                <a href="#"><span data-hover="Classes">Classes</span></a></li><li >
                                <a href="#"><span data-hover="Pricing">Pricing</span></a></li><li >
                                <a href="#"><span data-hover="About Us">About Us</span></a></li><li >
                                <a href="#"><span data-hover="Log In">Log In</span></a></li>   </ul>   
                     </div>
```

Comment: "bottom half of my menu to show" what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I want to know too.  I see the full buttons with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a fixed height(1.3em !important;) for A which is causing this issue.

`Please check this updated working fiddle:`http://jsfiddle.net/7tcrz38r/2/

Answer (score 0):

you have this declaration:

```
div#menu>ul>li>a {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 1.3em !important;
}
```

which, by the way, is repeated since it's declared some lines above

```
div#menu>ul>li>a {
    color: #868787;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 1px !important;
    margin: 17px 15px !important;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

Anyways, just remove that `overflow:hidden` property. However, you'll have the menu items showing twice because of that data-hover `span` you have. I don't know why are you using that, so consider if you need it or not. Of course, you can simply remove that `"height: 1.3em !important;"` as well, but I assume it's better to have a height than an overflow. anyways, it's a a decision you'll have to ponder